Get Value of Angular FormGroup FormControls Methods
So, let's say you have a FormGroup built as such:
  let formGroup = new FormGroup({
    control1: new FormControl(null),
    control2: new FormControl('x'),
    control3: new FormControl(46)
  });

Now let's say we want to access the value of control2.  I have seen this done multiple ways, but I have not been able to find much in the way of "best practices" or "preferred access methods".  As examples, I have seen these methods used throughout a single application, even in a single component.
Method 1: formGroup.controls.control2.value
Method 2: formGroup.value.control2
Method 3: formGroup.get('control2').value
For the record, the only way I can recall seeing it used prior to this application is formGroup.controls.control2.value so now I am trying to figure out the "best practice" for accessing these controls and their values.
Is this just simple redundancy where you can do the same thing in different ways?  Or are there actual differences that need to be accounted for with each of these methods?

There is no difference in those methods regarding on how to get the value, the difference depends if you want to access a feature in the control or not (formGroup.get('control2') vs formGroup.value.control2), so yes is just simple redundancy.
The redundancy exists because FormGroup and FormControl extends from AbstractControl, so both share the same abstract properties/methods (value, get ->AbstractControl, getRawValue...).
As a recommendation, perhaps a common/utility class could help you to avoid having multiple access methods to the same thing, the following example could help you, feel free to improve it as you wish.
class Test {
  test() {
    const formGroup = new FormGroup({
      control1: new FormControl(null),
      control2: new FormControl('x'),
      control3: new FormControl(46)
    });

    const value = this.getFormValue(formGroup, 'control1');
    console.log(value);
  }

  public getFormValue<GroupT extends {[K in keyof GroupT]: AbstractControl}>(
    form: FormGroup<GroupT>,
    name: keyof GroupT,
    options?: {useRaw?: boolean; value?: string}
  ): string {
    const {useRaw, value} = options || {raw: false, value: ''};
    const control = form.get(name as string);
    const result = useRaw ? control?.getRawValue() : control?.value;
    return result || value || '';
  }
}


Thank you, I don't think adding in a shared utility class would be feasible in this particular application based on the effort required and I am the only one on the team who seems to be bothered enough by the inconsistencies to dig into it and figure out if one way is 'right' and the other ways are 'wrong'.  But at least I can say "Now I know", and knowing is half the battle.
